# create an index from metada with GraphAware \ Neo4j \ OGM \ Annotations

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4j-php-ogm

I'm using **`GraphAware\Neo4j\OGM\`** for the management of nodes and relationships in Neo4j, to create the nodes I use the following metadata:

```
use GraphAware\Neo4j\OGM\Annotations as OGM;

    /**
     *
     * @OGM\Node(label="Contact")
     */
    class Contact 
    { ... }
```

in a cypher query it would be something like that

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Contact(firstname, email)
```

Comment: There is no metadata inference for creating indexes in the PHP OGM. You will have to create them manually in Neo4j.

Comment: thanks you @ChristopheWillemsen